# Create an object from nested struct definition in GoLang?

Tags: go, struct

Is there a way to create an object from a nested struct type

```
func main() {
    car := Car{}
    var wheel Car.Wheel
}

type Car struct {
    Wheel struct {
        name string
    }
}
```

I have a deep nested json. I am interested in operating on many of these nested structs separately.
I want to access the struct definition through the “root” definition .  Something like `Car.Wheel`  instead of explicitly defining `type Wheel struct` for many of my nested objects in the json

Comment: The easy path is to explicitly declare a named type for each nested struct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an object from a nested struct type

No, because there's no such thing as a "nested struct type". You don't have a type `Car.Wheel`, you have a type `Car`, with a field `Wheel`; that field's type is the unnamed type `struct { name string }`. You cannot refer to an unnamed type; it is unnamed. To refer to a type, you have to name it. You could do:

```
var wheel struct { name string }
```

And you'd be able to assign between `wheel` and `Car.Wheel`, because they're the same type; however, this is not particularly convenient (you'd have to write out the full type definition everywhere you use it), and it means you can't define any methods on the type, which may or may not be a limitation you care about.

Generally speaking, in Go, you just want to define a named type for each type you want to use, and those definitions would each be at the top level:

```
type Car struct {
    Wheel Wheel
}

type Wheel struct {
    name string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Car struct {
    model string
    wheel Wheel
}

type Wheel struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    car := Car{model: "Toyota"}
    car.wheel.name = "my wheel"

    fmt.Println("car model: ", car.model)
    fmt.Println("car wheel name:", car.wheel.name)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to put the Wheel struct outside of my Car. That's the issue I am trying to solve

Comment: @Hexy can I ask why you don't want to define them separately? I don't know the pros/cons but I'm dealing with someone else's library where they've done this and it makes it Very hard to work with, because I have to redfine the struct in my code to be able to use it as a type. Like when I want to store a list of them, how can I say `[]InternalUnnamedStructFromTheStructIDoKnowTheNameOf`? I can't think of any reason that would be worth this pain